# Why should we give rewriting permission to tmp of cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

Currently i'm using latest version of cakephp,When i try to install it it shows the error as temp folder is not re writable.

OK it is fine we can give ch-mod rewrite permission to that particular folder. But there is a reason behind everything.

I  tried to find why should we give to it , and what is the reason behind that but i can't get the answer clearly , so i'm expecting  it from you ,  can anyone help me to understand, thanks in advance...

Comment: CakePHP needs *write* permission on **tmp** folder, not *re-write*. I think you may be confusing file permissions with **.htaccess** rewriting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re asking why a **tmp** folder needs write access? Well, if you look in the folder, there are sub-folders for caching, logging, session, and tests if you run them.

CakePHP needs write access so it can write cache file, write any errors logs, write sessions to disk if you’ve configured CakePHP to save session data in your **tmp** folder.

I’m not sure how to explain this any clearer than, CakePHP needs write access to the **tmp** folder to, erm, write files.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation says:

> Make sure that this folder exists and that it is writable, otherwise the performance of your application will be severely impacted. In debug mode, CakePHP will warn you if it is not the case.

See: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-folder-structure.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It is ok but the reason ?